# OpenApi: generate java/kotlin DTOs out of multiple files

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have a problem with the imports of the generated code of the openapi-generator for Java and Kotlin.

Let's say I have a root.yaml/child1.yaml/child2.yaml with the following content:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Transfer:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: "child1.yaml#/components/schemas/Pet1"
        - $ref: "child2.yaml#/components/schemas/Pet2"
```

child1.yaml:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Pet1:
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - name
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
        tag:
          type: string
```

child2.yaml:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Pet2:
      type: object
      required:
        - id2
        - name2
      properties:
        id2:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name2:
          type: string
        tag2:
          type: string
```

In this case, I do not care for the entities in child1/child2 and I only want the Transfer-object to be build, so I fill the the modelsToGenerate-setting with Transfer only. My problem is that the generated Transfer class always contains imports for the childs, even when they are not needed. For example:

```
import com.model.Pet1
import com.model.Pet2

data class Transfer (
    val id: kotlin.Long,
    val name: kotlin.String,
    val id2: kotlin.Long,
    val name2: kotlin.String,
    val tag: kotlin.String? = null,
    val tag2: kotlin.String? = null
)
```

The generated class is not dependend on the childs, but the imports are always generated. Is there a setting or a workaround that I missed? The unnecessary imports also appear when Pet1 and Pet2 are generated, but Transfer is still not dependend on the childs. 
My use case is that I do have some very large models in the spec and I would like to split them into multiple files to reduce clutter/duplication without a public class for every single child.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself. You have to run a formatter like Google Java formatter after the classes are generated.